# Should I approve an edit that changes algorithm in a broken but accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I had [this suggested edit review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7414196) on which I'd like others' opinion.  For the avoidance of doubt, I'm absolutely sure it's a good faith edit on a wrong (but accepted) answer.

I'm not sure what to do.  The edit does change the algorithm (both fixing an off-by one on the offset and making column number `0` based rather than `1` based), so normally I would reject, but I feel like this is an edge case as the editor is plainly trying to make a non-working and accepted solution work.

My options seem to be:

1. Reject the edit and downvote the answer.
2. As per 1, but also leave a comment saying that I've seen the suggested edit and suggest the editor leaves their own answer.
3. Approve the edit as a general improvement to the situation

I read [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269892/838992), that I think would point me toward 3, but I'm not sure whether I'd call this edit minor. My instinct is to do 2, but I'm really not sure, so soliciting some advice / discussion.

Comment: I'm voting for #2 , as it seems to be a good compromise , not sure about #3 because it sounds like it's not quite a "general improvement" , rather more of a "small fix"

Comment: My vote is for #1.  Maybe #2 as well, but that question is so old that I'm not sure what good it would do.  Chances are that the OP won't bother coming back and changing the accepted answer to the more correct one.  Looking at the edit it seems like it changes a lot of what was there (I'm no python coder, so I could be wrong).  In any case, the explanation in the answer seems sound and anyone who just copy-paste-deploys code on the internet without testing and understanding it deserves what they get.

Comment: 4. Post a question about it at meta, so the wrong answer will get down-voted to oblivion.

Comment: Everybody that down voted needs to make sure they go back and upvote when the answer is fixed. Otherwise you all just did more harm than good.

Comment: In this case (when the intent is clearly changed the way I cannot clearly recognize as good) I rather skip the review in a hope that the (still active) author decides what to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Reject it for:

> **clearly conflicts with author's intent**
>   This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

If you think the answer is right, that's all.

If you know the answer is bad, downvote it.
Also upvote an appropriate comment, respectively tell what's wrong about the answer and how to correct it, maybe with a reference to the edit-suggestion if that helps.

(I see the suggestion was handled appropriately, including your reject-vote.)

Answer (score 5):

Since the author of the answer is active on the site, and this is the accepted answer on a fairly old question, I think you should:

1. reject the edit
2. write a comment to author, and hope he fixes the answer himself
3. clean up (remove downvote/add upvote as appropriate, delete comments)
4. write a question at meta asking if you did right

If 2 fails, then you skip directly to 4, and have the wrath of meta effect fall on the poor sod.